# Ionic 2 / refresh iFrame in Tabs

Tags: angular, ionic2

Inside my ionic 2 App i have 3 Tabs. One of the tabs has a integrated iFrame. I know this is not the best way, but currently i have no other option. 
Everytime if i come back to the tab with the iFrame, i need to refresh it. How can i do that.

Currently i set in tabs.html:

```
<ion-tabs (ionChange)="tabChange()">
```

and the Funktion tabChange() in tabs.ts publish an event:

```
this.events.publish('tabChange', this.change)
```

and in the page with the iframe i have to subscribe to this event:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public events: Events) {

this.events.subscribe('tabChange', (n) => {

  // refresh iFrame here

  })
}
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Do Ionic tabs have a routed version ? I mean, like for instance, Angular Material : you can either use tabs that will display a component, or tabs that will use a router-outlet to show routes. Do you have tabs with a router-outlet version ?

Comment: no, I did not. Dont know what you mean, sorry

Comment: I add @ViewChild('myiframe') myiframe and now i have access to the iframe. But this.myiframe.refresh() ends in error

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the solution. The `event.subscribe` must be inside `ionViewDidEnter` not the constructor so it is called everytime I go to the page with the iframe within.

```
ionViewDidEnter(){

    this.events.subscribe('tabChange', (n) => {

      let src: string = this.myiframe.nativeElement.src;
      this.myiframe.nativeElement.src = src;

      this.events.unsubscribe('tabChange')

    })

}
```